# Find multilined string with regex

Tags: .net, regex, excel

I'm trying to find a multilined string inside of HTML tags. This regex

```
<\s*form[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*/\s*form>
```

does it pretty well in Notepad++, if the setting `find \r and \n` is activated.

What i can't get done is to force this regex to work with Excel (using [a .Net Addon](http://seotoolsforexcel.com/working-with-regular-expressions-in-excel/), which lets execute regex). There this regex finds only one lined string (mean without \r, \n or both).

For example:

- if a string is `<form foo>bar</form>` - regex finds `bar`, as expected,
- If  a string is `<form foo>bar\r\nbaz</form>` - regex finds nothing.

How could this regex be adjusted to catch multilined strings too?

Comment: Maybe you can use a real html parser in your .net addon

Comment: @TimSchmelter i can't :(

Comment: If you feel the question isn't a duplicate it's best to make an edit to further explain how it's different and/or why the solutions from the other question don't apply here.

Comment: @Jeroen i don't need these ego games editors are playing here. Who is looking for described solution, will find it, with or without a notice, that an editor has a shmock he likes to publicly demonstrate. If you value this community, vote better for those who answered the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided the .Net Addon supports .NET Regex syntax, you may inject `(?s)` modifier into the expression to make the `.` match newline chars too:

```
(?s)<\s*form[^>]*>(.*?)<\s*/\s*form>
```

Comment: `(?s)` -  exactly - thats what i was looking for - a .Net regex modifier for catching new lines